# Best way of structure data in properties file

Tags: data-structures, properties

I am developing a web application and I need some parameters from properties files. These parameters have the following structure:

```
parameter1.field = Field 1
parameter1.value = Value 1
parameter2.field = Field 2
parameter2.value = Value 2
...
```

I personally don't like this data structure, and I'd like to organize them in a more simple way, like this:

```
parameter1 = Field1,Value 1
parameter2 = Field2,Value 2
...
```

My question is if there is any other way to organize information in a properties file for data like these, for example, in an array structure or something similar.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON file instead, which allows you for a more complicated structure.

There is no standard way to represent non-flat structures in a properties file, and everything that you do would be a custom solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. JSON could be an interesting solution, but I'm afraid I can't use it because all the apps my team and me are developing have to have the same structure, so data must be read from properties.